# Color is being processed strangely after uploading to YouTube

Tags: color, video

After uploading to YouTube, the green in my video is being processed with a weird tint (like a sea foam green). In the image below, I'm hoping for the blueish/green color on the left, but that color only shows in Safari (and sometimes Chrome) - otherwise it's mostly showing the color incorrectly.

Even more strange is when I use Quicktime on my Mac to screen record the video when the color is displaying incorrectly on YouTube, the end result when I play it back in quicktime shows the correct color. For example, watch my YouTube video:

, then see the screen capture here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7-2T7XJFKEKdklRQUpDaTdUYVU/view.

This is only happening with the green color, all the other colors are correct. I'm exporting from Final Cut Pro on a Mac, I've tried my color display on my Mac at Color LCD and Color LCD Calibrated. Any idea why the color is being processed incorrectly once it's playing in YouTube?

[image]

Comment: Just some considerations, the reply to your answer itself is a bit more extended and I have not the whole vision to suggest you except of check the profile you are using. But the variables are a lot, consider that this can differ if the video is played as flash player or html5 and also different browsers handles and apply color profiles in a different way. This is true also for images with embedded ICC profile. About the "green" but other colors, well, that green is shifted in a more visible way but i'm pretty sure all the colors get a slight modification.

Answer (score 0):

I see the correct color on Youtube. via Flash player on Windows 7.

Sounds like either a gamma issue with the errant players, not Youtube. Try VLC.

--or--

Your FCP output isn't properly tagged. Its colorspace is Rec 709 but it's tagged as Rec 601 (or something else).

Comment: On a mac, when I open VLC > Open Network > paste my youtube link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=heuPCADkS0o, then I see the correct color. But still don't see the correct color in Chrome on YouTube. Would you suggest changing the FCP output to Rec 709?

Comment: Yes, that should be the default.